# Extract part of a path

Tags: linux, shell, awk, sed

I have a variable that is a path of a windows folder.

I would like to handle the way with SED .

Example:

**Input:**

```
\\computer1\folder$
```

**Output:**

```
computer1
```

I would always pick the host name that is between \\ and \

Could someone give me a light?

Comment: This is a very simple regular expression, what problem are you having with it?

Comment: If you don't know regular expressions, read the tutorial at www.regular-expression.info. You're not going to learn it by having the answer spoon-fed to you here.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in a POSIX compatible shell:

```
% folder='\\computer1\folder$'
% folder="${folder/\\\\/}" # Remove leading '\\'
% printf "%s\n" "${folder%%\\*}"
computer1
```

Alternative with Bashism:

```
% folder='\\computer1\folder$'
% [[ "$folder" =~ '\\'([^\\]*) ]]
% printf "%s\n" "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
computer1
```

Answer (score 0):

For this scenario, `awk` is a better option. Use `awk -F'\' '{print $2}'`

Example

```
$> echo "\\computer1\folder$"|awk -F'\' '{print $2}'
```

Output

```
computer1
```

Or you can try putting it with a variable.

```
$> export val="\\computer1\folder$"

$> echo $val|awk -F'\' '{print $2}'
computer1
```

Comment: have you checked your expression ? It doesn't print anything

Comment: Yes. I copied it from Unix after checking. Maybe export doesn't work properly for some shell. Let me try hardcoding it too.

Answer (score 0):

With sed :

```
$ sed 's/\\\\\([^\]*\)\\.*/\1/' <<< '\\computer1\folder$'
computer1
```

The basic syntax for sed substitution command is `s/oldtext/newtext/`.

- `s` is for substitution command
- in the path string, every `\` must be escaped so it becomes `\\`
- `\([^\]*\)\` captures every non `\` character until next `\`
- the captured string is output with backreference `\1`

Answer (score 0):

With awk. `s` stands for "separator" and `a` stands for "any".

```
echo '\\computer1\folder$' | \
awk '{s="\\\\"; a=".*"; sub(a s s, ""); sub(s a, ""); print}'
```